# [React Native]Images don't load in Android

Tags: android, image, react-native

I have the following line of code that renders an image from a correct url(I checked it in the browser):

```
<Image source={{ url: group.Image }} style={styles.image} />
```

This works fine in iOS but on Android the images rendered blank, their size is correct but there's no actual image there.

RN version: 0.39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with the example from Facebook's documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html):

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
           style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

Check whether it works with this snippet of code. If it works maybe you have something wrong inside your styles.image which cannot be said without showing it to us.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it made me realise I wrote url instead of uri, stupid mistake.

Comment: Great! Good luck with your project :)

Comment: add a key value `key={index}`

Comment: For some reason I've seen many examples using `url` which works for iOS but not Android.